# how did /Users/wayneeseguin get into my path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I configuring my new Mac to use with Rails, and was installing the latest version of rvm on a Mac under OS X 10.8, and ended up with this PATH:

> echo $PATH
>   /Users/rickc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/rickc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/rickc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/rickc/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/wayneeseguin/.sm/bin:/Users/wayneeseguin/.sm/pkg/active/bin:/Users/wayneeseguin/.sm/pkg/active/sbin:/Users/rickc/.rvm/bin

Although it is not creating any difficulties (yet?), I do not understand how /Users/wayneeseguin... got into my path. I've looked through all the startup files for the bash shell, and cannot find this anywhere. Frustratingly mysterious; if anyone has an idea, please let me know!

thanks,
rixter

Comment: Did you use the devtools RVM installer?

Comment: did you find out where it was coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You probably got it by installing rvm.

Look for a line

```
source /etc/profile.d/sm.sh
```

in the /etc/profile file.

The /etc/profile.d/sm.sh is what actually puts it in there.